# Apache + mod_wsgi , google Oauth2.0 error 400: invalid_request

Tags: flask, google-compute-engine, mod-wsgi, google-oauth

A while ago i have made a website using Flask and the website ran on my localhost, i used google's Oauth2.0 for my user logins and it worked. i deployed the app on a server using Apache2 + mod_wsgi through google compute and made a new project for oauth2.0 (since google deleted my previous one) and changed my client_secret to fit that new project, but now whenever i try to use the login it gives me this,

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.

Request Details
response_type=permission id_token code
scope=openid email
openid.realm=
prompt=consent
access_type=offline
include_granted_scopes=true
redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/*external ip*?id=auth97080
client_id=*my_client_id*
ss_domain=*External Ip*
gsiwebsdk=shim
```

I have tried changing the authorized javascript origin but it kept using this ip even though i changed it through my credentials multiple times

Comment: It worked,  seems that oauth2.0 doesn't take numerical IP's so i just changed my ip using xip.io and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As explained oauth2.0 doesn't take numerical IP's so just changed ip using xip.io should work.